# SQL dynamically join to a user/data supplied table

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, join, oracle11g

I want something like:

```
SELECT * from metric_data m, 
    (SELECT table_for_join FROM join_tables WHERE from_table = 'usersupplied') u,
    WHERE m.id = u.id
```

Is this possble?

I'm using oracle 11g if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use dynamic sql. Something like this (sorry, I'm not able to test it at the moment, but I hope it should work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getMetricData (in_table_name varchar2)
IS 
  real_tab_name varchar(32);
BEGIN
  SELECT table_for_join into real_tab_name 
  FROM join_tables WHERE from_table = in_table_name;
  IF (real_tab_name IS NOT NULL) THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * from metric_data m, ' || real_tab_name || ' u 
   WHERE m.id = u.id';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll test later today

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* from metric_data m
LEFT JOIN join_tables u
ON(m.id = u.id AND u.from_table='usersuplied')
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, are you sure you understood the problem?  'join_tables' doesn't contain an 'id' column, and I see no mention of the third dynamic table I'm actually joining to.